# The best pattern to access objects through subrelation

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Which one is better? and why?

```
CurrentCustomer.Company.Employees.Select(x=>x.Name);
```

Or :

```
CurrentCustomer.GetCompanyEmployeeNames();
```

---

Other example:

```
CurrentCustomer.Company.Employees.where(x=>x.Post==EmpPosts.Manager).Select(x=>x.Name);
```

Or :

```
CurrentCustomer.GetCompanyManagerNames(); 
//And Comany has : 
//GetManagerEmployeeNames(); 
//And Employee has
//GetManagerNames(); And GetEmployeeNames(); methods
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Law of Demeter aka Protected Variations. It is one of GRASP principles of OO development.

The second is better as it allows the implementation to change.

In other words, when you expose the first interface, you cannot change it without changing all the code that uses it. Others wrote hundreds lines of code that makes use of yours and you are stuck.

In the secod approach, you **hide** the implementation so that you can change it in future versions and the client code doesn't change.

Comment: Edited my answer. If you are still in doubts, google for "protected variations" it is one of GRASP principles.